# REST returns List Items but Response is blank in SP2013

Tags: rest, csom

I am SOOOO frustrated ...

I have a jquery function to grab list data and when I log "data" I see the full {d} with a {results} holding all the list items. But when I run it through an $.each function to get a string I can return, when I log rsp, the debugger says "an empty string."

Here is my function:

```
function get_news(){
    var rsp = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://edrdbdev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Latest News')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
                rsp +=  "<p>" + item.Title + "</p>"
            });
        },
        error: function(error){
            rsp = JSON.stringify(error);
        }
    });

    console.log(rsp);
    return rsp;
} // end get_props function
```

I am going crazy and would greatly appreciate any advice or corrections. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding log statements inside the loop and see if you get proper results inside there.

Comment: I added console.log(item) as the first line in $.each but nothing is being logged

Comment: Perhaps there is no item in the list.

Comment: When I expand "data" from the first console.log, I see a {d} which when expanded shows all 7 items but inside the $.each, the console.log(item) isn't working and the console.log(rsp) is an empty string. I think the problem is in $.each(data.d.results) but I don't know what else to use.

Comment: I change the log inside the loop to console.log(item.Title) and in Safari, all 7 items are logged.

Comment: Is this a variable scope issue? rsp should be available throughout the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` perform an **asynchronous** HTTP (Ajax) request. That means sending the request (or rather receiving the response) is taken out of the normal execution flow.

In your example, `return rsp` is executed **before** the function you passed as success callback was even called.

### Solutions

There are basically two ways how to solve this:

- Make the AJAX call synchronous.
- Restructure your code to work properly with callbacks.

Please refer [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) for a more details

Below is demonstrated the modified version with callback usage:

```
function get_news(result){
    var rsp = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://edrdbdev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Latest News')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
                rsp +=  "<p>" + item.Title + "</p>"
            });
            result(rsp);    
        },
        error: function(error){
            result(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });    
} 



//Usage
get_news(function(content){
    console.log(content);
});
```

Comment: Can I use a promise? Using .then would ensure that the data has loaded, so then I could inject the data into the div and then append the div to the page, I think???

Comment: Sure, a good idea indeed

Comment: Great ... now I just have to figure it out ... LOL